# Align text by first letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to detect the first letter of the input text and align the text according to this letter.

I need to find the first letter (first letter means character of english, hebrew, arabic,  etc).

so:

---

**"a"**

This should be aligned to the left. (first letter is the letter **a**, not **"**)

---

**"א**

this should be aligned to the right (cause there is hebrew letter).

---

**....שלום hellow**

This should be aligned to the right.

---

I found these jsfiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/qHLXX/

```
$('input, textarea').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val().charAt(0).charCodeAt(0) < 200 ? 
    $(this).css('direction','ltr') : $(this).css('direction','rtl');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/qHLXX/1/

```
<input type="text" dir="auto"><br>
```

The first jsfiddle works but it checks the first character of the string and not the first letter, so **"א** aligned to the left.

The second jsfiddle doesn't work in internet explorer (like everything else).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check every char and return true if is Hebrew alphabet char

```
$('input, textarea').keyup(function () {
    if (!hebrewchar($(this).val())) {
        $(this).css('direction', 'ltr')
    } else {
        $(this).css('direction', 'rtl');
    }

});

function hebrewchar(stringaValue){
    var HebrewChars = new RegExp("^[\u0590-\u05FF]+$");
    for(var i=0;i<stringaValue.length;i++){
        if (HebrewChars.test(stringaValue[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qHLXX/23/

Comment: Beautiful solution!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to remove all non-letters, and then the logic would apply to the first character of what remains:

```js
$('input, textarea').keyup(function() {
  var value= $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z\-\u0590-\u06FF]/g,'').substr(0,1);
  value.charAt(0).charCodeAt(0) < 200 ? $(this).css('direction','ltr') : $(this).css('direction','rtl');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"><br>
<textarea></textarea>
```